# identify and delete spam comments from 3000 pending comments

Tags: comments

i have a wordpress site that has more than 3000 pending and 0 spam comments. i want to identify and delete only spams. there are ways to delete all pending but i want to first identify spams and then delte them. There was no spam guard plugin earlier. I have just installed akismet. using wordpress 3.2. Please guide me.

Comment: I have the same issue. The idea is to re-evaluate all existing comments in batch, and marking them as spam or not, using like, the Akismet plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

take a look on this link.it'll helpful.[Anti Spam Plugin](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/18/featured/11-anti-spam-plugins-for-wordpress.html). my opinion is antispambee is good.

Answer (score 1):

I think the gratest solution is here [Anti Spam Bee](http://antispambee.com/). Try this.

Comment: `Anti Spam Bee` doesn't seem to have an option to batch process existing comments...